# Record saves only 20% of the time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a model "Project" which `has_many: Subprojects, through: Project_Associations`.

Essentially when users create a project they can choose Subprojects or smaller components of the project that apply to it.  This works fine in my dev environment the Projects can save normally but on Heroku in Production users often report that they can not save a Project unless they don't check off any of the Subprojects.  I have had the same problem but I have also had times where it has worked just fine.

This is a dump from the logs when it did not work:

```
Started POST "/projects" for 205.167.40.131 at 2019-01-29 13:59:57 +0000
2019-01-29T13:59:57.133251+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-29T13:59:57.133172 #16]  INFO -- : [0606ad52-0c91-4cb0-b60a-71048099e7a5] Processing by ProjectsController#create as HTML
2019-01-29T13:59:57.137677+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-29T13:59:57.137577 #16]  INFO -- : [0606ad52-0c91-4cb0-b60a-71048099e7a5]   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"QJhasohAhfaoih919BoPIIGPdqhxinginSHian5d+Gg==+", "project"=>{"name"=>"New Project Name", "summary"=>"Project Summary ", "go_live"=>"2019-06-15", "precentage_complete"=>"0", "start"=>"2019-01-17", "subproject_ids"=>["", "4", "1", "8", "10", "9", "13", "11"]}, "Start Project"=>"Create Project"}
2019-01-29T13:59:57.147658+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-01-29T13:59:57.147534 #16] DEBUG -- : [0606ad52-0c91-4cb0-b60a-71048099e7a5]   User Load (3.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 51], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2019-01-29T13:59:57.152028+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-01-29T13:59:57.151925 #16] DEBUG -- : [0606ad52-0c91-4cb0-b60a-71048099e7a5]   Subproject Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "subprojects".* FROM "subprojects" WHERE "subprojects"."id" IN (4, 1, 8, 10, 9, 13, 11)
2019-01-29T13:59:57.176569+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-01-29T13:59:57.176430 #16] DEBUG -- : [0606ad52-0c91-4cb0-b60a-71048099e7a5]    (10.6ms)  BEGIN
2019-01-29T13:59:57.181619+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-01-29T13:59:57.181485 #16] DEBUG -- : [0606ad52-0c91-4cb0-b60a-71048099e7a5]   Subproject Exists (1.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "subprojects" WHERE "subprojects"."name" = $1 AND ("subprojects"."id" != $2) LIMIT $3  [["name", "Updates"], ["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2019-01-29T13:59:57.185301+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-01-29T13:59:57.185215 #16] DEBUG -- : [0606ad52-0c91-4cb0-b60a-71048099e7a5]   Subproject Exists (1.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "subprojects" WHERE "subprojects"."name" = $1 AND ("subprojects"."id" != $2) LIMIT $3  [["name", "Communication"], ["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2019-01-29T13:59:57.188964+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-01-29T13:59:57.188877 #16] DEBUG -- : [0606ad52-0c91-4cb0-b60a-71048099e7a5]   Subproject Exists (1.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "subprojects" WHERE "subprojects"."name" = $1 AND ("subprojects"."id" != $2) LIMIT $3  [["name", "Project Meeting"], ["id", 8], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2019-01-29T13:59:57.197124+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-01-29T13:59:57.197011 #16] DEBUG -- : [0606ad52-0c91-4cb0-b60a-71048099e7a5]   Subproject Exists (4.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "subprojects" WHERE "subprojects"."name" = $1 AND ("subprojects"."id" != $2) LIMIT $3  [["name", "Training Delivery"], ["id", 10], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2019-01-29T13:59:57.204607+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-01-29T13:59:57.204479 #16] DEBUG -- : [0606ad52-0c91-4cb0-b60a-71048099e7a5]   Subproject Exists (6.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "subprojects" WHERE "subprojects"."name" = $1 AND ("subprojects"."id" != $2) LIMIT $3  [["name", "Training Design"], ["id", 9], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2019-01-29T13:59:57.208083+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-01-29T13:59:57.207989 #16] DEBUG -- : [0606ad52-0c91-4cb0-b60a-71048099e7a5]   Subproject Exists (2.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "subprojects" WHERE "subprojects"."name" = $1 AND ("subprojects"."id" != $2) LIMIT $3  [["name", "Training Development"], ["id", 13], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2019-01-29T13:59:57.233123+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-01-29T13:59:57.232977 #16] DEBUG -- : [0606ad52-0c91-4cb0-b60a-71048099e7a5]   Subproject Exists (14.9ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "subprojects" WHERE "subprojects"."name" = $1 AND ("subprojects"."id" != $2) LIMIT $3  [["name", "Train the Trainer"], ["id", 11], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2019-01-29T13:59:57.247200+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-01-29T13:59:57.247058 #16] DEBUG -- : [0606ad52-0c91-4cb0-b60a-71048099e7a5]   Project Exists (4.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."name" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["name", "Upfront Examiner Adjudication"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2019-01-29T13:59:57.251205+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-01-29T13:59:57.251106 #16] DEBUG -- : [0606ad52-0c91-4cb0-b60a-71048099e7a5]    (2.8ms)  ROLLBACK
2019-01-29T13:59:57.252262+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-01-29T13:59:57.252173 #16] DEBUG -- : [0606ad52-0c91-4cb0-b60a-71048099e7a5]    (0.5ms)  BEGIN
2019-01-29T13:59:57.257433+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-01-29T13:59:57.257342 #16] DEBUG -- : [0606ad52-0c91-4cb0-b60a-71048099e7a5]   Subproject Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "subprojects" WHERE "subprojects"."name" = $1 AND ("subprojects"."id" != $2) LIMIT $3  [["name", "Updates"], ["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2019-01-29T13:59:57.259329+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-01-29T13:59:57.259246 #16] DEBUG -- : [0606ad52-0c91-4cb0-b60a-71048099e7a5]   Subproject Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "subprojects" WHERE "subprojects"."name" = $1 AND ("subprojects"."id" != $2) LIMIT $3  [["name", "Communication"], ["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2019-01-29T13:59:57.263853+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-01-29T13:59:57.263763 #16] DEBUG -- : [0606ad52-0c91-4cb0-b60a-71048099e7a5]   Subproject Exists (1.9ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "subprojects" WHERE "subprojects"."name" = $1 AND ("subprojects"."id" != $2) LIMIT $3  [["name", "Project Meeting"], ["id", 8], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2019-01-29T13:59:57.267172+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-01-29T13:59:57.267079 #16] DEBUG -- : [0606ad52-0c91-4cb0-b60a-71048099e7a5]   Subproject Exists (2.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "subprojects" WHERE "subprojects"."name" = $1 AND ("subprojects"."id" != $2) LIMIT $3  [["name", "Training Delivery"], ["id", 10], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2019-01-29T13:59:57.272418+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-01-29T13:59:57.272320 #16] DEBUG -- : [0606ad52-0c91-4cb0-b60a-71048099e7a5]   Subproject Exists (4.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "subprojects" WHERE "subprojects"."name" = $1 AND ("subprojects"."id" != $2) LIMIT $3  [["name", "Training Design"], ["id", 9], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2019-01-29T13:59:57.274358+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-01-29T13:59:57.274276 #16] DEBUG -- : [0606ad52-0c91-4cb0-b60a-71048099e7a5]   Subproject Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "subprojects" WHERE "subprojects"."name" = $1 AND ("subprojects"."id" != $2) LIMIT $3  [["name", "Training Development"], ["id", 13], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2019-01-29T13:59:57.280155+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-01-29T13:59:57.280028 #16] DEBUG -- : [0606ad52-0c91-4cb0-b60a-71048099e7a5]   Subproject Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "subprojects" WHERE "subprojects"."name" = $1 AND ("subprojects"."id" != $2) LIMIT $3  [["name", "Train the Trainer"], ["id", 11], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2019-01-29T13:59:57.282022+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-01-29T13:59:57.281944 #16] DEBUG -- : [0606ad52-0c91-4cb0-b60a-71048099e7a5]   Project Exists (0.9ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."name" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["name", "Upfront Examiner Adjudication"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2019-01-29T13:59:57.289942+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-01-29T13:59:57.289832 #16] DEBUG -- : [0606ad52-0c91-4cb0-b60a-71048099e7a5]    (7.5ms)  ROLLBACK
2019-01-29T13:59:57.291030+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-29T13:59:57.290946 #16]  INFO -- : [0606ad52-0c91-4cb0-b60a-71048099e7a5]   Rendering projects/new.html.erb within layouts/application
2019-01-29T13:59:57.299919+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-01-29T13:59:57.299823 #16] DEBUG -- : [0606ad52-0c91-4cb0-b60a-71048099e7a5]   Subproject Load (2.6ms)  SELECT "subprojects".* FROM "subprojects" ORDER BY "subprojects"."name" ASC
2019-01-29T13:59:57.309977+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-29T13:59:57.309816 #16]  INFO -- : [0606ad52-0c91-4cb0-b60a-71048099e7a5]   Rendered projects/_form.html.erb (18.5ms)
2019-01-29T13:59:57.310122+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-29T13:59:57.310033 #16]  INFO -- : [0606ad52-0c91-4cb0-b60a-71048099e7a5]   Rendered projects/new.html.erb within layouts/application (18.9ms)
2019-01-29T13:59:57.311921+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-29T13:59:57.311825 #16]  INFO -- : [0606ad52-0c91-4cb0-b60a-71048099e7a5] Completed 200 OK in 174ms (Views: 18.7ms | ActiveRecord: 75.8ms)
2019-01-29T13:59:57.318562+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/projects" host=magic-trackr.herokuapp.com request_id=0606ad52-0c91-4cb0-b60a-71048099e7a5 fwd="205.167.40.131" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=189ms status=200 bytes=8018 protocol=https
```

From the projects_controller:

```
def new
    @project = Project.new
  end

  def create
    @project = Project.create(project_params)

    if @project.save
      flash[:success] = "Project started"
      redirect_to tasks_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "project not added"
      render 'new'
    end

  end
```

_Form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@project, html: {class: "form-group"}) do |f| %>
<%= render 'errors' %>
<%= f.label :name %>
<%= f.text_field :name, id: "project-name", class: "form-control" %>
<%= f.label :summary%>
<%= f.text_field :summary, id: "go-live", class: "form-control" %>
<%= f.label :go_live %>
<%= f.date_field :go_live, id: "go-live", class: "form-control" %>
<%= f.label :precentage_complete %>
<%= f.number_field :precentage_complete, id: "go-live", class: "form-control" %>
<%= f.label "Start Date" %>
<%= f.date_field :start, id: "date-field", class: "form-control" %>
<br />
<%= f.label "Included subprojects" %>
<br />
<ul class="list-group sub-task">

  <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:subproject_ids, Subproject.order(:name), :id,
                              :name, {class: "form-control"}) do |box| %>
  <li class="list-group-item">
  <%= box.check_box + box.text %>
  </li>
  <% end %>

  </ul>

<%= f.submit name: btn_name, class: 'btn btn-primary' %>

<% end %>
```

From looking at the logs of a successful save and an unsuccessful one I can't really see any reason the record is not saving.  But the trouble is always when the user adds Subprojects to their Project.

Project.rb

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tasks, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :project_assocaitions
  has_many :subprojects, through: :project_assocaitions

  validates :name, uniqueness: true, presence: true, length: {minimum: 2}
```

Project_Assocaition.rb (I realize association is spelled incorrectly:

```
class ProjectAssocaition < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :subproject
end
```

SubProject.rb

```
class Subproject < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :project_assocaitions
  has_many :projects, through: :project_assocaitions
    validates :name, uniqueness: true, presence: true, length: {minimum: 2}
end
```

Comment: Please post the model code for `Project` and `Subproject` models. Specifically, it would be good to see the validations you have in each model.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that, I've added those models/validations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your `Project` model and `Subproject` model require the name to be unique. This means if someone adds a project with the same name it will fail to save. This is also a problem for the `Subproject`.

So if I try to create a project named "Branding Update" with a subprojects of "Kickoff" and "Demo" - this will succeed if the database is empty. Then I create another project named "New Product" that has the same named subprojects of "Kickoff" and "Demo" - this will *not* succeed in saving because "Kickoff" and "Demo" need to be globally unique and they've already been used for the "Branding Update" project.

Maybe you want to scope the uniqueness in the Subproject like this:

```
class Subproject < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :project_assocaitions
  has_many :projects, through: :project_assocaitions
  validates :name, uniqueness: {scope: :project_id, message: "should only be one per project"}, presence: true, length: {minimum: 2}
end
```

Comment: Oh I think I see what you're saying.  My goal is to make it so that an admin could not create multiple "Subprojects" with the same name **but** that multiple projects can have any combination of the same subprojects.

Comment: Ok what happened was I had added these validations after we started having some users test it and there were already some duplicated Subprojects.  So I think if a user tried to save a Project with one of those duplicated Subprojects they would run into problems.